# How do Leviathans reproduce?

Tags: aliens, spaceship, farscape

I know that Moya gave birth to Talyn and that this was the result of Peacekeepers trying to make a Leviathan gunship, presumably by some sort of artificial means. But how would Leviathans normally reproduce?

Comment: When a mummy Leviathan and a daddy Leviathan love each other very much, there's a special hug they do.

Comment: Do you really want to know?

Answer (score 2):

I think we can only judge from "They've Got a Secret" and "The Hidden Memory" and from what little evidence is added by "The Way We Weren't".

In the former, D'Argo falls down a shaft and accidentally breaks a Peacekeeper shield, releasing scads tiny biomechanoid "cells" (for lack of a better word) that apparently get Moya pregnant. These cells were confirmed by Zhaan to come from Moya herself. The baby grows inside a special incubation area until it is mature enough to "be born" and free themselves from the parent. The difficulty with Talyn was that he was not a normal Leviathan.

We later find out that the shield was placed there to sabotage the gunship project.

The upshot of all this is that Leviathans appear to reproduce asexually, since the biomechanoid "sperm" that impregnated Moya came from her as well.

Comment: It beggars belief the a communal multi-cellular species reproduces asexually. It's far more likely that Leviathans share sperm (via their transfer ships).

Comment: @Richard: Well, Rygel farts helium, which is a physical impossibility. I don't think the writers cared much about the science. They just wanted to tell good stories and be internally consistent. Anyway, it seems a little too easy for a Leviathan to impregnate itself. Perhaps both happen, but I would wager that it more often happens asexually.

Comment: Even we were to assume that natural parthenogenesis in social animals is impossible, based purely on the lack of such examples on Earth, are we sure the Leviathans are not an engineered species?

Comment: No, but it's far more likely that they reproduce sexually (or at very least share DNA) because why not?

Comment: @Jonah - We're sure they are.  There was an ep where Rygel's voice got on-screen as one of their creators.

Comment: This link specifically identifies Tayln as a male: [link](http://farscape.wikia.com/wiki/Talyn)                                                                     and Moya was consistently referred to as "she" so there are 2 identified sexes.

Comment: @sfhq_sf: Yet the "sperm" was positively identified as being from Moya. Leviathans are at the very least hermaphroditic, which makes the pronouns a matter of preference.

Comment: @John Sensebe: The transcript of this episode "They've got A Secret" here [link] (http://transcripts.terrafirmascapers.com/110.htm)         _Zhaan: It shouldn't be. The particles are bio-mechanoid. Just like Moya. But I think you're right, (She brings up a hologram of the particles) they are fragments from Moya’s bio-polymer structure. From the explosion._  And later _John: Yeah, it's a catalyst, the catalyst for pregnancy._
Moya was already inseminated, the shield acted as some kind Leviathan diaphragm.

Comment: @sfhq_sf, you didn't look far enough into the episode. *Zhaan: (Looking up from her work) Except it's not a virus. This test just confirmed that the particles are not a distinct organism like a virus. They are actually made up of Moya’s genetic material. They are a part of Moya. They must be fragments from the explosion.
John: No they can't be fragments. They are all perfectly uniform in size.
Zhaan: But John, they are a part of Moya.*